# how to set commands to the bot from other files

Tags: oop, aiogram, telegram-webhook

I need the bot to respond to the start command, but I don’t know how to use it correctly in the main bot file.

start.py:

```
from aiogram import types
from bot import router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart

class StartCommandHandler:
    @router.message(CommandStart())
    async def start(message: types.Message):
        await message.reply("hello")
```

bot.py:

```
import logging
import sys
from typing import List
from aiohttp import web
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.webhook.aiohttp_server import SimpleRequestHandler, setup_application
from Config.EnvService import Env
from Config.ServerService import Server

router = Router()

class BotMars(Bot):
    WEBHOOK_PATH = Server.createWebhookPATH(Env.get("BOT_TOKEN"))
    APP = app = web.Application()

    def __init__(self, token, dp):
        self.TOKEN = token
        self.DP = dp
        self.BASEBOT =  Bot(
                            self.TOKEN, 
                            parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML, 
                            session=Server.getServerSession()
                        )

    async def on_startup(self):
        await self.BASEBOT.set_webhook(
            url=f"{Server.getWebhookURL()}{self.WEBHOOK_PATH}",
            drop_pending_updates=True
        )
        webhook_requests_handler = SimpleRequestHandler(dispatcher=self.DP, bot=self.BASEBOT,)
        webhook_requests_handler.register(self.APP, path=self.WEBHOOK_PATH)

    def webhook_handler(self):
        setup_application(self.APP, self.DP, bot=self.BASEBOT)
        web.run_app(self.APP, host=Server.getServerHost(), port=int(Server.getServerPort()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_router(router)
    bot = BotMars(Env.get("BOT_TOKEN"), dp)
    dp.startup.register(bot.on_startup)
    bot.webhook_handler()

    from App.start import start
```

I tried to do it like I did before in functional programming just import everything (*), but it was not successful, please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about Magic Filters etc.

Here is an **example** of registering event handlers from another file:

bot.py

```py
import asyncio

import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F
from aiogram.filters import Command

# Import the necessary functions
from handlers import get_start, get_message

TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')

dispatcher = Dispatcher()

async def update():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    # Registration of event handlers with the necessary filters
    dispatcher.message.register(get_start, Command(commands=['start']))
    dispatcher.message.register(get_message, F.text)

    while True:
        await dispatcher.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(update())
```

handlers.py

```py
from aiogram.types import Message

async def get_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('You called the "start" command')

async def get_message(message: Message):
    await message.answer('You wrote me a text message')
```

Links:

1. https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/filters/index.html
2. https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/filters/command.html (Command)
3. https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html (F)